# MySQL/PHP: Can I get the values being updated or deleted from a MySQL query?

Tags: php, mysql, logging

I have a simple PHP website and currently I log all the MySQL database queries into a "log" table so there's a record of what changes were made when and by whom.  The problem is: for all update and delete queries the old value isn't logged.

Is there a simple way to return the old value(s) which were updated or deleted?  I started playing with parsing query strings, but it seems messy, complicated and simply wrong.

Here's an example of what I'd like to do: If the query being executed is:

```
UPDATE members SET email='joe@this.com' WHERE memberId=123;
```

I'm currently recording a table like so:

```
+------+------------+-------------------------------------------------------------+
| User | Date       | Query                                                       |
+------+------------+-------------------------------------------------------------+
| joe  | 2013-03-29 | UPDATE members SET email='joe@this.com' WHERE memberId=123; |
+------+------------+-------------------------------------------------------------+
```

What I'd like the table to look like:

```
+------+------------+-------------------------------------------------------------+--------------+
| User | Date       | Query                                                       | Old Values   |
+------+------------+-------------------------------------------------------------+--------------+
| joe  | 2013-03-29 | UPDATE members SET email='joe@this.com' WHERE memberId=123; | joe@that.com |
+------+------------+-------------------------------------------------------------+--------------+
```

(Notice the new column on the right with the old changed data.)

I realize this could get tricky with multiple values being changed at once, but any guidance on where to look would be great.  Thanks!

Comment: If running in an appropriate transaction (i.e. SERIALIZABLE or REPEATABLE READ?), a SELECT before the UPDATE would hold true. But .. how *is* the log being done? If done via triggers, the old values should be immediately available.

Comment: The log.php file is included in every other file and the query is passed to its function before it is executed.  So the log.php file looks simply like:

    function log($query) {
        $sql = "INSERT INTO log SET Date=NOW(), User='".$_SESSION['username']."', Query='$query'";
        mysql_query($sql);
    }

That's it.

Comment: Since this logging is a client-side artifact (i.e. it's not a trigger or a database service/proxy) then consider using a consolidated UPDATE/DELETE function that has more knowledge of the situation. I know that such logging/auditing solutions are offered for .NET (which is what I use), so I would suspect that there are similar DIY or available wrappers/generators for something like PDO or other DAL providers.

Answer (score 0):

If you're asking what I think you are, then no, you cannot. Once data has been replaced or deleted, its kind of gone forever.

If you seriously wanted to do this, you'll need to keep **versions** of the data and only do inserts that set a new update counter or something and that is really not going to be fun for you.

Comment: What I'd like is to keep a record of the old data being replaced.  My first thought was reverse-engineering the querying string, but it seemed overly complicated which was why I was looking for alternate solutions.  (So if I were executing a "DELETE FROM users WHERE password='123'" I would like to perform a "SELECT * FROM users WHERE password='123'" in order to observe the delta.  For updates less data needs to be kept, of course.)

Comment: @Bing Since this form of control is ultimately *only an artifact of the client code*, what about requiring that all DELETE operations are done via a special function?

Comment: @castis It's actually not unheard for such "advanced" logging facilities - although they often be part of the database (or functionality provided therein) or are provided by some code generator/DAL. The point of a log isn't so much as to be able to archive as to be able to *audit*.